# Create Service Once, and call different components Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Service for translations in localstorage I want to do in my template header component html :

`<p>{{trans('menu.items.news')}}</p>`

and I have a method in header.component.ts:

```
 trans(key){

    const TRANS = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('translations'));

    return key.split('.').reduce(function(prev, curr){
      return prev ? prev[curr] :  null;
    }, TRANS || self);
  }
```

but I want that this method call others components in root module , once because now is in header component only. :(

I have too and service for getting translations in header html select list

```
changeTranslation(e){

    localStorage.setItem('language', e.target.value);

    localStorage.removeItem('translations');

    this.translation.getTranslation().subscribe(response => localStorage.setItem('translations', JSON.stringify(response)));
  }
```

how implement only or call service translation once in the app module for use it in other components? find the best way. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use behaviorsubject for that, please see the example

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-behaviorsubject-example-l2b3dw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Fuser.service.ts)

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `trans` method across components, you should instead of put it in a angular service, then use DI to inject that service into any component you want to use `trans` method.

Comment: Super, gracias... me toco hacerlo así.  Thanks I did it